# How can i show Stack Bar chart and line chart both in one chart?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to display information as year wise .So I will use Stacked bar chart.But I also want to display line chart for some other information on the same graph.
So How can i achieve this ?

For Example,
I have below information.

---

### Item Name|Year   2010    2011   2012     2013

Wheat            100     90      200      260

Rice             80      70      150      190

---

Total Production 180     160     350      450

Total Production 
should be        200     250     400      550.

So,
For displaying production year wise,I will use stacked bar chart.
But I want to display Total production and Total Production should be as line chart.

So how can i achieve this ?[image]

Comment: I have suggested a duplicate that should be your case, check it out and let me know.

Comment: If I combine Line chart and Stacked Bar chart then it will not make sure that how much range both chart will take ? In many case,it is not possible to take same range for both the charts.If they take different range intervals then chart will not be displayed like image attached above.

Comment: set same range on axis?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I got my answer.I have used Multi Axis chart and it is perfectaly suit my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Multi Axis chart and it is perfectly suit my needs.Muti-Axis chart provides a way to add more than one charts into one-chart.And we can Customize all added chart by applying customizer class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StackedColumnLine` chart type because i don't think there's a `StackedBarLine` Chart type.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeoeL.jpg

Comment: But In my Jasper Studio,I cant see this type of chart.Can you tell me how to import this type of chart ?

Comment: I have done R & D..But HTML5 charts is only available in Commercial Version of JasperSoft.But can you please tell me any other way to do so ?

Comment: Are you using community edition? I am using Professional edition. If, you are using community edition and are not able to use then that means it's limited to professional edition only. You can try 30 days trial period because i don't know any other work-around. @user1234

Comment: I have downloaded Jaspersoft studio 6.2 Commercial Edition for 30 days trial.And I got HTML5 chart option in that..But Can you tell me how I can configure Jasper soft studion 6.2 into my existing application made in Eclipse.??